# How to use HttpContext of an existing web site, from a web service?

Tags: asp.net

I am building a web service which uses some of an existing web site's methods.
However, some classes and methods cannot be used (for example Redirect - which obivously throws an exception when not invoked from a web site's context).
Now I came to a section in code where

```
 HttpContext.Current.Application.Get(keyNames.EncodedKey)
```

Is used.
(Where `keyNames` is a struct, and `EncodedKey` is a string.)
but `HttpContext.Current` is null..

So my question is - What is a valid substitution for `HttpContext.Current.Application.Get`?

I should mention that I've only checked this from a unit test, not the web service itself and following Darin's answer I realize that is the problem, so the question now is- how to mock HttpContext.Current (using moq)?

Thanks you.

Comment: A web service should run in the context of the containing website, so you will have access to `HttpContext.Current` (once you're in the web service, rather than the unit test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is an .asmx web service then you will have no problems using `HttpContext.Current`. The only problem is with your unit test. It's never going to work because `HttpContext.Current` is always `null`. You could use an abstraction : [HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.aspx) which could be mocked in the unit test. If it is a WCF web service then it is a whole different matter.

Comment: +1 and thanks a lot Darin. can you give me a hint on how to mock it?

Comment: @Oren, this will depend on the mocking framework you are using.